# Hidden Words..!

Tags: visual, english

Today i came across a cool picture that has SIX hidden words in it. I ended up with just 3. Can you able to find all the SIX words in it.? Here is it. Take a look at it.

[image]

Comment: I'm happy to accept each and everyone's answer. But what to do, SO allows only one answer to be accepted. I accept @Sir SC. And really like the contribution of Dark Truth also.

Comment: Only one answer so far found 7 separate words

Comment: Couldn't resist, there are at least 2 separate upside-down words as well, although they overlap with rightside-up words

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the words:

> Book , Story, Words, Page, Novel, Read

image:

> [image]

Comment: Made the image visible without following a link.

Answer (score 8):

> [image]
>
>  
>  BOO & BOOK
>  
>  NO & NOVEL
>  
>  STORY & OR
>  
>  words & or
>  
>  PAGES & AGE
>  
>  read & ad
>  
>  HI (in floorboards)

Added, upside-down words:

> ON (in upside-down NOVEL)
>  
>  HIP & HI (beginning with H from rightside-up HI,
>                 the P in HIP is upside-down "d" from "read")

Comment: That 'HI' was a nice catch!

Comment: page, ages, Tory

Answer (score 4):

Story:

> On the woman:
>  The **S** is in her hair.
>  The **T** is on her shirt.
>  **O** and **R** are on the book.
>  **Y** is where the book and her leg meet.

Page:

> On the boy:
>  The **P** is on his trousers.
>  **A** and **G** are on his shirt to the left of his arm.
>  The **E** is on his sleeve.

Words:

> On the plant.
>  At the bottom right edge of the leaves.

Read:

> On the dog and girl.
>  **R** and **E** on each of the dogs ears.
>  **A** and **D** on the girls hair.

Comment: finished earlier than you and uploaded a screenshot mate :) but good explanation on details

Comment: @Sir SC still found 4 before you put the screenshot up. Still well done.

Comment: Since you found most of them, let me help you with the rest: "Book" in the man's glasses, "Novel" in the armchair's right arm and legrest. Edit: nvm should've refreshed first...

Answer (score 3):

The words are

> **BOOK**, **STORY**, **WORDS**, **NOVEL**, **PAGES**, AND **READ**

as marked below:

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

> novel, story, book, page, words, read
>  Novel in the chair
>  Book in the glasses
>  Story in the mother + book
>  words in the tree
>  Page in the teenager lying on the couch
>  read in the dog ears + girl